# Cannot play wav audio on armv7 with Qemu with gst-launch-1.0

Tags: c++, qt, audio, arm, gstreamer

I'm trying to play a WAV audio file using Qt with C++, it fails then I tried to play it using gst-launch-1.0, it also fails. This is all using an armv7 toolchain and the running under QEMU.

After failing in C++ using code

```
QAudioDecoder decoder;
QFileInfo fileInfo(WAV_FILE_NAME);
decoder.setSourceFilename(fileInfo.absoluteFilePath());
decoder.start();
if (decoder.state() == QAudioDecoder::DecodingState)
    qDebug() << "Decoding";
```

It fails with error

```
0:00:00.167441195 29283 0xf375dc00 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3583:gst_base_src_start_complete:<source> pad not activated yet
0:00:00.176093619 29283 0xf375dc00 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3583:gst_base_src_start_complete:<source> pad not activated yet
0:00:00.237290158 29283 0xf37fc660 WARN            uridecodebin gsturidecodebin.c:921:unknown_type_cb:<uridecodebin0> warning: No decoder available for type 'audio/x-wav'.
0:00:00.238382698 29283 0xf37fc660 WARN               decodebin gstdecodebin2.c:4640:gst_decode_bin_expose:<decodebin0> error: no suitable plugins found:
Missing decoder: WAV (audio/x-wav)

0:00:00.239083745 29283 0xf37fc660 WARN            uridecodebin gsturidecodebin.c:988:no_more_pads_full:<uridecodebin0> error: no suitable plugins found:
../../../gst-plugins-base-1.14.4/gst/playback/gstdecodebin2.c(4640): gst_decode_bin_expose (): /GstPlayBin:playbin1/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0:
no suitable plugins found:
Missing decoder: WAV (audio/x-wav)

0:00:00.240739264 29283 0xf37fc660 WARN                typefind gsttypefindelement.c:1231:gst_type_find_element_loop:<typefind> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:00.240853974 29283 0xf37fc660 WARN                typefind gsttypefindelement.c:1231:gst_type_find_element_loop:<typefind> error: streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
```

That's why I tried to use

```sh
./gst-launch-1.0 -v uridecodebin uri=file:///home/vbox/myaudio.wav
```

Then I got this error as well

```
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: source = "\(GstFileSrc\)\ source"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-wav
Missing element: WAV demuxer
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: No decoder available for type 'audio/x-wav'.
Additional debug info:
../../../gst-plugins-base-1.14.4/gst/playback/gsturidecodebin.c(921): unknown_type_cb (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.
Additional debug info:
../../../gst-plugins-base-1.14.4/gst/playback/gsturidecodebin.c(988): no_more_pads_full (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0:
no suitable plugins found:
../../../gst-plugins-base-1.14.4/gst/playback/gstdecodebin2.c(4640): gst_decode_bin_expose (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0:
no suitable plugins found:
Missing decoder: WAV (audio/x-wav)

ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I'm not sure what's really missing. Also, this is the output of gst-inspect-1.0

```sh
$> ./gst-inspect-1.0 | grep wav
   audiovisualizers:  wavescope: Waveform oscilloscope
   typefindfunctions: application/x-shockwave-flash: swf, swfl
   typefindfunctions: audio/x-wav: wav
   typefindfunctions: audio/x-wavpack: wv, wvp
   typefindfunctions: audio/x-wavpack-correction: wvc
```

What could be missing here?

Comment: I guess `wavparse:  wavparse: WAV audio demuxer` is required, if not more. Depending on your .wav file. I would check your install for additional packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "wavparse" plugin should be available.